# Complete SQLite table from another table

Tags: sqlite

I am having some problems for updating a SQLite table from another.

The first table is called 'blogs' and has a column called 'link'. The first row of this column is 'https://fundooprofessor.wordpress.com/'.

The second table is called 'apple' and has a column called 'domain'. The first row of this column is 'fundooprofessor.wordpress.com'.

I want to update the table 'apple' from the table 'blogs', and the point of connection to be column link and the column domain.

I wrote the following:

```
UPDATE apple SET lang = (SELECT lang FROM blogs WHERE apple.domain like '%' + blogs.link + '%')
```

And the 'lang' column in apple is not completed from the 'lang' column in blogs.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition you must interchange `blogs.link` and `apple.domain` because you want `blogs.link` to contain `apple.domain`.
Also the concatenation operator in SQLite is `||` and not `+`.
So use this:

```
UPDATE apple 
SET lang = (SELECT lang FROM blogs WHERE blogs.link like '%' || apple.domain || '%')
```

If there is a case that `blogs` does not contain a `link` under these conditions, then use `COALESCE()` like this:

```
UPDATE apple 
SET lang = COALESCE(
  (SELECT lang FROM blogs WHERE blogs.link like '%' || apple.domain || '%'),
  lang
)
```